vagrant up command issues for it is not working properly, what could be the issue
I am having this error using vagrant up. How do i correct it?
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'eurolinux-vagrant/centos-stream-9'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Dell\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\eurolinux-vagrant-VAGRANTSLASH-centos-stream-9\\9.0.43
\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "packer-centos-stream-9-x86_64_1716224292657_77968", "--vsys", "0",
 "--unit", "10", "--disk", "C:/Users/user/VirtualBox VMs/packer-centos-stream-9-x86_64_1716224292657_77968/packer-cent
os-stream-9-x86_64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\Dell\.vagrant.d\boxes\eurolinux-vagrant-VAGRANTSLASH-centos-stream-9\9.0.43\virtualbox\box.o
vf...
OK.
0%...E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 1436 of f
ile VBoxManageAppliance.cpp

